# Can't Install PIL 1.7

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have python 2.7.3 and I want to install PIL 1.7.
I downloaded "PIL-1.1.7.win32-py2.7" and try to install it but it shows me an error messege that it can't find python 2.7 in the registry.

> "python version 2.7 requried, which wasn't found in the registry".

I double check and I'm sure that I have python 2.7.3.
what is the problem?

Comment: Is your python 64 bit perhaps?

Answer (score 15):

As the message says, PIL installer can't find registry keys, this because python installer put values in 32 bit OS version path "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\2.7" but for 64 bit OS version it should be set in "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Python\PythonCore\2.7".

Easy fix is to copy and paste below in a text file, then change the extension to .reg and run it, it will add the required registry, then install PIL.

Copy from here to the end:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Python\PythonCore\2.7]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Python\PythonCore\2.7\Help]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Python\PythonCore\2.7\Help\Main Python Documentation]
@="C:\\Python27\\Doc\\python273.chm"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Python\PythonCore\2.7\InstallPath]
@="C:\\Python27\\"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Python\PythonCore\2.7\InstallPath\InstallGroup]
@="Python 2.7"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Python\PythonCore\2.7\Modules]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Python\PythonCore\2.7\PythonPath]
@="C:\\Python27\\Lib;C:\\Python27\\DLLs;C:\\Python27\\Lib\\lib-tk"
```

Comment: I found it slightly easier to start cmd.exe as administrator and then use `reg copy HKLM\SOFTWARE\Python HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Python /s`.

Comment: @WanderingLogic You should put that as an answer, or edit the one above.

Comment: @WanderingLogic - put that as a solution!  I would love to upvote you.

Comment: WanderingLogic's solution worked for me.  Very quick and easy.  Many thanks!

Comment: Wandering Logic's response wokred likea charm

Answer (score -1):

Try pre compiled Windows binaries:
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pil

Comment: Removed the old one? Also use Pillow instead of PIL: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/

Comment: I didnt even inatall the old one, before the installation start it say that python 2.7 not found

Comment: What is the complete shell output? How did you installed Python?

Comment: "python version 2.7 requried, which wasn't found in the registry".
I installed python few months ago and it works fine, I don't remember how did I installed it.. not something special I guess