# Moving existing Anaconda installation to new Windows

Tags: python, windows, installation, anaconda

I would like to ask a simple, and maybe a little bit strange, question. I wasn't able to find all answers on this site, so I hope I'm not making spam with this thread.

I installed Anaconda (Python 2.7 32-bit) in my Windows 7 (64-bit) on a different partition than my operating system. After installing Windows 8.1 (64-bit) I would like to keep all my scripts, environment, setting for Spyder etc. in new installation. I was thinking about "adding" existing Anaconda installation to Windows, to save myself from reinstalling everything and copying important files. Is it possible to be done in a simple way?

There are ways to add Python to registry ([How to add Python to Windows registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17872234/how-to-add-python-to-windows-registry)) and system environment variables ([How to add to the pythonpath in windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-7)) but, still, Anaconda installer does more (Start menu folders, icons etc.).
In short words: I would like to use Anaconda installer to make everything but copying new files into existing folder.

To be honest, I think there is something wrong in my way of thinking about this so I have to ask this question - how do you move your Python installation when you install new system or reinstall old one?

My first, silly answer is: install new Anaconda and then just insert old files in a place of a newly created installation. But I'm almost sure it will lead to problems with paths and working of programs - or maybe I'm too cautious and it's actually a good way to move installation to new system?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you'll be able to do everything you want in a "simple" way. Upgrading an OS is a major change. You'll just have to reinstall and reconfigure Anaconda. Then copy over your own scripts as necessary. Some applications save config files that you can use to import your systems (such as Outlook), so you could ask if that's something Anaconda supports via their support channels. If not, then you'll probably just have to reinstall.