# Python cannot load cx_Oracle on Windows 7

Tags: python, python-2.7, windows-7

I installed python-2.7.amd64.msi and cx_Oracle-5.1.2-11g.win-amd64-py2.7.msi.

I've poked around a lot with PATH and PYTHONPATH environment variables but nothing has helped loading the cx_Oracle module.  Currently PYTHONPATH is set to
C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages

My exceedingly basic program is

```
import sys
print sys.path

import cx_Oracle

conn_str = u'xxx/xxx@server/XXX'
conn  = cx_Oracle.connect(conn_str)
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute(u'select * from table')
conn.close()
```

The program output is:

```
['C:\\Users\\terry\\IdeaProjects\\PythonScripts', 'C:\\Python27\\Lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\python27.zip', 'C:\\Python27\\DLLs', 'C:\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\Python27']
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "OracleTest.py", line 4, in <module>
import cx_Oracle
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I have also added the Registry entries as detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17872234/how-to-add-python-to-windows-registry)

This works fine on Linux so it seems I have something wrong with the windows setup.  But I've pretty much run out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

This problem turned out (I think) to be that I had not set the ORACLE_HOME environment variable in Windows. This must point to your Oracle instantclient directory e.g. ORACLE_HOME=C:\instantclient_11_2

The "I think" part of the story is that even after setting that it did not help.  I uninstalled cx_Oracle and reinstalled it from scratch.  This time I also used the cx_Oracle.EXE from the python web site NOT the cx_Oracle.MSI file from sourceforge.  In theory they would do the same thing.  But in theory it wouldn't have taken me over a day to get the environment set up.