# How to change easyGUI python text color

Tags: python, textcolor, easygui

I want to change the text color of `msgbox`, `ynbox` and the output text in easyGUI.

Please help!

Comment: have a look at the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from [this site](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2009-October/072275.html):

> EasyGUI won;t help change colour, it is just a way of making
>   a command line script act like a GUI - by popping up dialog
>   boxes to capture input and dsplay messages. It replaces
>   raw_input and print with dialogs.
>
> --------code--------

```
from WConio import textcolor

apples_left = 5

print "There are",(textcolor(4)),apples_left,(textcolor(7)),"left in the basket."
```

> ---
>
> The output works, but there is one snag.  I think that I am leaving 
>   something out because it has the word "None" on both sides of the 
>   variable.

This could be an easy solution for your problem.

You may get [WConio](https://docs.python.org/2/using/windows.html#wconio) from here:
http://newcenturycomputers.net/projects/wconio.html

If you face python not found error at the time of installation then you may try following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30982219/6918812).

---

**UPDATE:**
There is one more package named [Colorama](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/colorama), which is cross-platform for colored terminal text and pretty much stable. You may give it a try as well.