# How to add Python to Windows registry?

Tags: python, windows, nltk

I want to work with Natural Language Toolkit, but I can't set up the software. When I run it, it gives me an error message "**Python version -32 required, which was not found in the registry**"
I'm using Windows 10, and my python is a 32-bit version. 
I tried the solutions provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17872234/how-to-add-python-to-windows-registry) but none worked. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you type `where python` into command, what do you get?

Answer (score 0):

According to this Issue, Try this:

```
python -m pip install nltk
```

You can follow "[Setting up Python 3.5 and numpy and matplotlibon your own Windows PC or laptop](http://web.cs.wpi.edu/~cs1004/a16/Resources/Windows/SettingUpPython_Windows.pdf)" document for install Python correctly on windows.