# "No python.exe found in" error message while installing orange

Tags: orange

I am trying to install Orange and it throws an error message saying that python.exe was not found. I already have python installed. I am wondering what is the problem. [image]

Comment: I suspect it's looking for Python either in the system path or in the registry somewhere - probably the latter, and getting an empty string when it was expecting a path. If you want to debug this yourself I'd try using [procmon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) with the installer running to try and see how it's trying to detect Python. However procmon is very noisy so might take a bit of work to filter down the data to the bit you need.

Comment: Or there's instructions for checking / fixing the Python registry entries here: [How to add Python to Windows registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17872234/how-to-add-python-to-windows-registry)